# React - my map function on my array component is not defined when I try to declare it somewhere else

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to build an input form for a project I'm working that submits user data to a database. some of the input fields that are required have over 100 selections that user chooses from. So I wanted to separate those data choices into their own files and them pass props to a select input group to dynamically generate those options. But I'm running into an issue when I try to declare my input component on my form page. I'm getting cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I think its because I'm declaring the input component in the choices file and also the form file. I'll supply the code below so it makes a little more sense.

This is the code that supplies the array data to the input. Its a very long file so ill only post part of it

```
const BuildingChoices = () => {

    const buildingArray = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "ACB",
            value: "ACB"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "ADH",
            value: "ADH"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "AHG",
            value: "AHG"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "ANB",
            value: "ANB"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "AND",
            value: "AND"
        }, 
        {
            id: 6,
            name: "ARC",
            value: "ARC"
        }, 
        {
            id: 175,
            name: "WIN",
            value: "WIN"
        },
        {
            id: 176,
            name: "WMB",
            value: "WMB"
        },
        {
            id: 177,
            name: "WPR",
            value: "WPR"
        },
        {
            id: 178,
            name: "WWH",
            value: "WWH"
        } 
    ]

    return (
        <SelectInput arrayData={buildingArray} />
    )
}

export default BuildingChoices
```

Here is the select input field that where the options get dynamically generated based on the array passed to it.

```
import React from 'react'

const SelectInput = (props) => {
   
    return (
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <label className="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">{props.dataName}</label>
            <select onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value} name={props.name} className="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01"> 
            <option disabled>Choose...</option>
            {props.dataArray.map(data => (
                <option key={data.id} value={data.value}>{data.name}</option>  
                ))}
            </select>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default SelectInput
```

And then this is the component where the input gets rendered onto the page. It's at the very bottom of the code. I'm pretty sure this is my problem because I'm declaring the  in multiple files.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import SelectInput from "../SelectInput"

const Prjt_Metadata_Form = () => {

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        project_id: '',
        building: 'Choose...',
        measure_type: '',
        status: '',
        staff_lead: '',
        staff_colead: '',
        analyst: '',
        project_description: '',
        nonenergy_benefits: '',
        baseline_start_date: '',
        reporting_period_start_date: '',
        length_baseline_period_days: '',
        length_reporting_period_days: ''

    });

    const { project_id, building, measure_type, status, staff_lead, staff_colead, analyst, project_description,
        non_energy_benefits, baseline_start_date, reporting_period_start_date, length_baseline_period_days, length_reporting_period_days } = inputs


    const onChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setInputs({
            ...inputs,
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const body = {
                project_id, building, measure_type, status, staff_lead, staff_colead, analyst, project_description,
                non_energy_benefits, baseline_start_date, reporting_period_start_date, length_baseline_period_days, length_reporting_period_days
            }

            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/prjt_metadata', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            window.location = '/'
            console.log(response)

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        };
    }
    return (
        <div style={{ minHeight: '45vh' }} className="container d-flex align-items-center mt-5">
            <div className="card border-secondary bg-secondary text-center mb-3" >
                <div className="card-body text-black">
                    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Project ID</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="project_id" className="form-control" value={project_id} onChange={onChange} />
                                </div>
                                <SelectInput
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={building}
                                name="building"
                                dataName="Building"
                                />
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this working are very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

Look at how you render your `SelectInput`:

```js
<SelectInput
  onChange={onChange}
  value={building}
  name="building"
  dataName="Building"
/>
```

Then in `SelectInput` you map over a prop `dataArray` which you do not pass as a prop.

```js
props.dataArray.map(data => (
  <option key={data.id} value={data.value}>{data.name}</option>  
)
```

## Alternative solution

If you don't the `SelectInput` to be flexible regarding the data used, you can outsource your `buildingChoices` as a constant to a separate file `data.js` and include it in your `SelectInput` to map over it. The relevant parts in your `SelectInput.js` should then look something like this:

```js
import { buildingChoices } from 'data.js';

buildingChoices.map(data => (
  <option key={data.id} value={data.value}>{data.name}</option>  
)
```

However, you could also pass the `buildingChoices` constant as a prop when rendering `SelectInput

```js
import { buildingChoices } from 'data.js';

<SelectInput
  dataArray={buildingChoices}
  onChange={onChange}
  value={building}
  name="building"
  dataName="Building"
/>
```

Comment: That worked! I just exported the BuildingChoices file to the form and then passed the prop to the selectinput. Thanks for putting the idea in my head!

Answer (score 0):

Your SelectInput component is mapping from props.dataArray but in your Prjt_Metadata_Form component your SelectInput is missing the dataArray

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a High Order Component approach (HOC)?

```js
const BuildingChoices = (Component) = (props) => {

    const buildingArray = [
      // { ... }
    ];

    return (
        <Component arrayData={buildingArray} {...props} />
    )
}

export default BuildingChoices(SelectInput);
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
<BuildingChoices
  onChange={onChange}
  value={building}
  name="building"
  dataName="Building"
/>
```